# vue - Invalid value for dynamic directive argument (expected string or null): undefined

Tags: vue.js

hi I want Use dynamic argument for a directive 
, this is my HTML code

```
<div id="app5">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <button v-on:[eventName]="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>
```

and this is my vue instance

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#app5',
    data: {
        message: 'sgdfhfds hfdsdfhhdfshsdf',
        eventName:'click'
    },
    methods: {
       ....
    }
})
```

but don't worked and console gave me this error

> Invalid value for dynamic directive argument (expected string or null): undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your template is defined in the DOM which has the consequence of attributes getting lowercased.

This behavior is mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments):

> When using in-DOM templates (templates directly written in an HTML file), you should also avoid naming keys with uppercase characters, as browsers will coerce attribute names into lowercase.

So basically the template is this:

```
<button v-on:[eventname]="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
```

Your component has no `eventname` property, hence the `undefined`.

You will need to change the `eventName` property to `eventname`, or don't use DOM templates which means you will need to define the template in a string or pre-compile the templates using a build system like webpack and vue-loader.